# javaOptions with sbt docker:publishLocal and docker run

Tags: docker, sbt, sbt-docker

If I was running my application sans Docker, I would do something like this:

```
./myapp -Dconfig.file=conf/application.prod.conf -Dlogger.resource=logback.prod.xml
```

In fact, I can do even better and put them into by `build.sbt` file:

```
// Production Mode
javaOptions in Production ++= Seq(
  "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.prod.conf",
  "-Dlogger.resource=logback.prod.xml"
)
```

and then they will be applied when I run my app:

```
./myapp  # options now applied via build.sbt
```

When I build my app with `sbt docker:publishLocal`, then run it with docker run, the `javaOptions` do not take effect.

How can I get these `javaOptions` to take effect when I `docker run` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a work-around answer.  You can set the `dockerEntrypoint` like so:

```
// build.sbt
dockerEntrypoint := Seq("bin/myapp", "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.prod.conf", "-Dlogger.resource=logback.prod.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

`javaOptions` can be supplied to `sbt-native-packager` with

```
javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq(
  // -J params will be added as jvm parameters
  "-J-Xmx2048m",
  "-J-Xms256m"
)
```

Note that these options will be applied to all generated packages (Debian, Rpm, etc.), not just Docker. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/853).